# what do it mean 0x010f in PE characteristics

Tags: windows, portable-executable

Characteristics of My `PE File` is `010f`.

'`0100`' mean `Image_File_32Bit_Machine`.

I don't know what It is mean '`000f`'?

`0100` or `000f -> 010f`..

Help~

Comment: If you do an Internet search for `IMAGE_FILE_32BIT_MACHINE` you'll find all the other flags. It's also not clear what your programming question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer can be found in winnt.h in the SDK include folder.  the 0x0F represents these flags being set in characteristics:

```
#define IMAGE_FILE_RELOCS_STRIPPED           0x0001  // Relocation info stripped from file.
#define IMAGE_FILE_EXECUTABLE_IMAGE          0x0002  // File is executable  (i.e. no unresolved externel references).
#define IMAGE_FILE_LINE_NUMS_STRIPPED        0x0004  // Line nunbers stripped from file.
#define IMAGE_FILE_LOCAL_SYMS_STRIPPED       0x0008  // Local symbols stripped from file.
```